# Azure databricks autoloader spark streaming unable to read input fil

Tags: bigdata, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, databricks-autoloader

I have setup streaming job using autoloader feature and input is located at azure adls gen2 in parquet format.below is the code.

```
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")\
          .options(**cloudfile)\
          .schema(schema).load(staging_path)
df.writeStream\
    .trigger(processingTime="10 minutes"))\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)\
    .foreachBatch(writeBatchToADXandDelta)\
    .start()
```

This code throws an error as below

```
py4j.Py4JException: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 115) (172.20.58.133 executor 1): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file /mnt/adl2/environment=production/data_lake=main/tier=ingress/area=transient/domain=iotdata/entity=screens/topic=sensor/vendor=abc/source_system=iot_hub/parent=external/dataset=screens/kind=data/evolution=2/file_format=parquet/source=kevitsa/ingestion_date=2022/08/03/13/-136567710_c96a862c2aaf43cfbd62025cd3db4a48_1.parquet.
..
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$2.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$2.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:333)
    ... 18 more
```

what could be the reason for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you find the latest `Caused by` message? But it looks like the broken file

Comment: @Alex Ott I have added caused by in question.pls have a look.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like you have a broken file in your location. You can use `ignoreCorruptFiles` option ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/auto-loader/options.html#generic-options)) to skip broken files instead of failing.